# Errorchecked heap with malloc() function

Tags: malloc, heap-memory

I am having trouble understanding what this source code does. Not only that but I continuously receive the same window whenever I run debug of this source code. Below is the provided source code as well as screen shots of the output error and the pop up window. If there is someone out there that can break down this source code and guide or point me in the right direction to get this source code working I would greatly appreciate it.

```
`#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

void *errorchecked_malloc(unsigned int);    //Function prototype for errorchecked_malloc()

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *char_ptr;     //A char pointr
    int *int_ptr;       //An integer pointer
    int mem_size;

    if (argc < 2)       //If there aren't command line arguments,
        mem_size = 50;  //use 50 as default value.
    else
        mem_size = atoi(argv[1]);

    printf("\t[+] allocating %d bytes of memory on the heap for char_ptr\n", mem_size);
    char_ptr = (char *)errorchecked_malloc(mem_size);   //Allocating heap memory

    /*if (char_ptr == NULL) {   //Error checking, in case of malloc() fails
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not allocate heap memmory.\n");
        exit(-1);
    } */

    strcpy_s(char_ptr, char_ptr[36], "This is memory located on the heap.");
    printf("char_ptr (%p) --> '%s'\n", char_ptr, char_ptr);
    printf("\t [+] allocating 12 bytes of memory on the heap for int_ptr\n");
    int_ptr = (int *)errorchecked_malloc(12);   //Allocated heap memory again

    /*if (int_ptr == NULL) {            //Error checking incse malloc() fails
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not allocate heap memmory.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }*/

    *int_ptr = 31337;               //Put the Value of 31337 where int_ptr is pointing
    printf("int_ptr (%p) --> '%s'\n", int_ptr, *int_ptr);

    printf("\t [-] freeing char_ptr's heap memory...\n");
    free(char_ptr);                 //Freeing heap memory

    printf("\t [+] allocating another 15 bytes for int_ptr\n");
    char_ptr = (char *)errorchecked_malloc(15); //Allocating more heap memory

    /*if (char_ptr == NULL) {           //Error checking incase malloc() fails
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not allocate heap memmory.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }*/

    strcpy_s(char_ptr, char_ptr[11], "new memory");
    printf("char_ptr (%p) --> '%s'\n", char_ptr, char_ptr);

    printf("\t[-] freeing int_ptr's heap memory...\n");
    free(int_ptr);                  //Freeing heap memory
    printf("\t[-] freeing char_ptr's heap memory...\n");
    free(char_ptr);                 //Freeing the other block of heap memory

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void *errorchecked_malloc(unsigned int size) {      //An errorchecked_malloc function
    void *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(size);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not allocate heap memory.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFpDw.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8H4u.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some contexts, it may be possible for a program to recover gracefully from a failed attempt to allocate storage.  Consequently, while some languages treat allocation failure as a fatal error, the C Standard specifies that `malloc()` may return a null pointer if it is unable to allocate usable storage (the language of the Standard would suggest that it is required to do so, except that in some environments that would not be practical).

Although having a failed `malloc()` yield a null pointer rather than a fatal error may be helpful in cases where graceful recovery is possible, it is less useful in cases where a program needs a certain amount of memory in order to do anything useful, and wouldn't be able to behave usefully without it.  In such cases, having to follow every `malloc()` by a null check would be a waste of programmer effort and code space.  Consequently, it is often useful to have a function which behaves like `malloc()` when space is available, but which is guaranteed never to return anything other than a valid pointer; if it can't return a valid pointer, it won't return at all.  The code above looks like an implementation of such a function along with a test harness for it.